# Using time intervals with numpy datetime64 type in matplolib's bar-plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to make a horizontal bar plot, where the bars represent subsequent time intervals. This is my approach so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

date1 = np.datetime64('2014-12-31')
date2 = np.datetime64('2014-10-30')

fig = plt.figure( figsize=(12,8) )
ax1 = fig.add_subplot( 111 )

# make horizontal bar plot
ax1.barh( 1., width=(date1-date2), height=.3, left=date1, align='center' )

plt.show()
```

Matplotlib does not like this, though. This is the error message I get:

`TypeError: ufunc add cannot use operands with types dtype('float64') and dtype('<m8[D]')`

Sounds like matplotlib is unhappy about the time-interval being used as the bar's width. Any hint how to make matplotlib happy again?

I am using `numpy 1.15.1` and  `matplotlib 2.2.3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? Not very clear how would you like the hight to a specific timestamp point.

```
width = (date1-date2) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
ax1.barh(1., width=width, align='center')

ax1.set_xticklabels([date2 + np.timedelta64(x, 'D') for x in range(1, int(width)+1)])

plt.show()
```

Comment: nice, indeed, thank you! `date1` and `date2` are, however, both arrays with up to 20 elements. It's no problem to put the `barh` into a `for` loop, but I am having trouble to re-label the xticks correctly...

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: just a note: instead of `ax1.set_ticklabels`, I can also do a `fmt=matplotlib.dates.mdates.DateFormatter('%Y')` and `ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter( fmt)`